# urlretrieve hangs when downloading file

Tags: python, urllib

I have a very simple script that uses urllib to retrieve a zip file and place it on my desktop.  The zip file is only a couple MB in size and doesn't take long to download.  However, the script doesn't seem to finish, it just hangs.  Is there a way to forcibly close the urlretrieve?...or a better solution?

The URL is to a public ftp size.  Is the ftp perhaps the cause?

I'm using python 2.7.8.

```
url = r'ftp://ftp.ngs.noaa.gov/pub/DS_ARCHIVE/ShapeFiles/IA.ZIP'
zip_path = r'C:\Users\***\Desktop\ngs.zip'

urllib.urlretrieve(url, zip_path)
```

Thanks in advance!

---Edit---

Was able to use ftplib to accomplish the task...

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
import zipfile

ftp_site = 'ftp.ngs.noaa.gov'
ftp_file = 'IA.ZIP'
download_folder = '//folder to place file'
download_file = 'name of file'
download_path = os.path.join(download_folder, download_file)

# Download file from ftp
ftp = FTP(ftp_site)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('pub/DS_ARCHIVE/ShapeFiles') #change directory
ftp.retrlines('LIST') #show me the files located in directory
download = open(download_path, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + ftp_file, download.write)
ftp.quit()
download.close()

# Unzip if .zip file is downloaded
with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, "r") as z:
    z.extractall(download_folder)
```

Comment: I'm unable to get it to work as `nodename nor servername provided, or not known`

Comment: Do you intentionally use regexp for both url and zip_path instead of a string?

Comment: @EriksDobelis Not sure what you mean...? I'm fairly new to python, so not sure the difference...

Comment: A string prefixed with r is a regular expression not an ordinary string. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html?highlight=regular%20expression

Comment: @EriksDobelis A string prefixed with r is a raw string, and thus is helpful for regex. You'll find raw strings to be ideal for file names and URLs also.

Answer (score 3):

urllib has a very bad support for error catching and debugging. urllib2 is a much better choice. The `urlretrieve` equivalent in urllib2 is:

```
resp = urllib2.urlopen(im_url)
with open(sav_name, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(resp.read())
```

And the errors to catch are:

```
urllib2.URLError, urllib2.HTTPError, httplib.HTTPException
```

And you can also catch socket.error in case that the network is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python requests library with requests-ftp module. It provides easier API and better processes exceptions. See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp and http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/